# XML parsing in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml-parsing, rexml

I am using a REXML Ruby parser to parse an XML file. But on a 64 bit AIX box with 64 bit Ruby, I am getting the following error:

```
REXML::ParseException: #<REXML::ParseException: #<RegexpError: Stack overflow in 
regexp matcher: 
/^<((?>(?:[\w:][\-\w\d.]*:)?[\w:][\-\w\d.]*))\s*((?>\s+(?:[\w:][\-\w\d.]*:)?[\w:][\-\w\d.]*\s*=\s*(["']).*?\3)*)\s*(\/)?>/mu>
```

The call for the same is something like this:

```
REXML::Document.new(File.open(actual_file_name, "r"))
```

Does anyone have an idea regarding how to solve this issue?

Comment: Is that your beast of a regex or is it from REXML?

Comment: It is from REXML. It's not a regex i've written. I am just using REXML to parse an xml document

Comment: So, REXML is giving that "Beast of a regex" :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I almost immediately found the answer.

The first thing I did was to search in the ruby source code for the error being thrown.
I found that regex.h was responsible for this.

In regex.h, the code flow is something like this:

```
/* Maximum number of duplicates an interval can allow.  */
#ifndef RE_DUP_MAX
#define RE_DUP_MAX  ((1 << 15) - 1)
#endif
```

Now the problem here is RE_DUP_MAX. On AIX box, the same constant has been defined somewhere in /usr/include.
I searched for it and found in

```
/usr/include/NLregexp.h
/usr/include/sys/limits.h
/usr/include/unistd.h
```

I am not sure which of the three is being used(most probably NLregexp.h).
In these headers, the value of RE_DUP_MAX has been set to 255! So there is a cap placed on the number of repetitions of a regex!

In short, the reason is the compilation taking the system defined value than that we define in regex.h!

This also answers my question which i had asked recently:
[Regex limit in ruby 64 bit aix compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924762/regex-limit-in-ruby-64-bit-aix-compilation)

I was not able to answer it immediately as i need to have min of 100 reputation :D :D
Cheers!

Answer (score 12):

I've had several issues for REXML, it doesn't seem to be the most mature library. Usually I use [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) for Ruby XML parsing stuff, it should be faster and more stable than REXML. After installing it with `sudo gem install nokogiri`, you can use something like this to get a DOM instance:

```
doc = Nokogiri.XML(File.open(actual_file_name, 'rb'))
# => #<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0xf1de34 name="document" [...] >
```

The documentation on the official webpage is also much better than that of REXML, IMHO.

Comment: I want to know if this is a specific issue with ruby 64 bit. The same issue is not reproducible on 32 bit box. And if there is a work around for the same rather than installing some other library.

Comment: @Bharath: The better place to report this would be the Ruby bugtracker, then.

Comment: @Bharath: could also well be that your XML file is simply too large or too deeply nested. Maybe you should try some XML stream parser, in that case.

Comment: Then why is that the same file gets parsed in 32 bit ruby? Ideally speaking, 64 bit ruby should be capable of all the activities done by a 32 bit ruby library. Is it that ruby 64 bit has some limitations? If so, is there any documentation for the same?

Comment: @Barath: No, I rather think it's a bug. As I said, this wouldn't surprise me, most people use Nokogiri instead of REXML for some time now.

Comment: The file has just a two level nesting. The file itself is just around 54kb. So not really sure what is causing this issue.

Comment: But I have a sneaking suspicion that the problem is specific to aix box. On AIX box, i found the following line of code causing issue:  word_wrap(decode_field(column[:column_name], @name), line_width = 800)

Comment: The following error was being thrown: ActionView::TemplateError: too big quantifier in {,}: /(.{1,800})(\s+|$)/ ... when i dug deep into ruby code, i found that word_wrap was using a regex match. This was failing. even on irb, the same issue persisted. Finally I had to reduce the number of times a regex can repeat i.e {,} value. Then it worked. And the most important thing is that this was happening on 32 bit AIX box!!! So obviously, somewhere there is some restriction.